# Angular NG Zorro thousand separators

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using **[NG ZORRO](https://ng.ant.design/components/input/en)** for my Angular Typescript web application. Does anyone know how to add number field to thousand separators, here is my code

```html
<nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Origination is required!">
        <nz-input-group nzAddOnAfter="%">
            <input formControlName="my-input" nz-input type="number"  />
        </nz-input-group>
    </nz-form-control>
</nz-form-item>
```

Comment: `<input>` element with `type="number"` only accept the numerical value. Thus with a thousand separator, it is not recognized as a numeric value. You should use the default `<input>` element, which is with `type="text"`.

Comment: @core114 check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530794/2089677

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parser(nzParser) to achieve it

in HTML file

```
<nz-input-number [(ngModel)]="value" [nzParser]="parser"></nz-input-number>
```

in component.ts

```
parser = (value) => {
value = parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g, ''));
const numberFormatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
const formatted = numberFormatter.format(value);
return formatted;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

number type does not support thousand separator, please try using `nz-formatted-number` something like below (untested)

```
<input formControlName="my-input" nz-input nz-formatted-number nzFormattedNumberPrecision="0" nzFormattedNumberSeparator="," type="text" />
```

`nzFormattedNumberPrecision` -> for **0** and `nzFormattedNumberSeparator` -> **,**

Comment: I tried this but not worked for me

Comment: do you have a accessor file for this?

Answer (score 1):

###### TLDR; Check [this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjrigd?file=src/app/app.component.ts) using a custom [formatter](https://ng-zorro.gitee.io/components/input-number/en#components-input-number-demo-formatter)

---

NG ZORRO has an special input dedicated to numbers with [a lot of features](https://ng-zorro.gitee.io/components/input-number/en), first; instead of `nz-input-group` along with `input`; try `nz-input-number` along with `nz-input-number-group`. Then you can specify a custom formatter:

```html
<nz-input-number-group nzAddOnAfter="%">
  <nz-input-number [nzFormatter]="formatter" [(ngModel)]="demoValue" [nzStep]="1000"></nz-input-number>
</nz-input-number-group>
```

With the formatter; you basically tell the input to replace its current value with another one. Internally, the original value stays:

```js
// this formatter replaces adds a comma every three digits, ex: 1000 --> 1,000
formatter = (value) => `${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
```

If your are not used to regular expressions you can do ugly stuff like this:

```js
// ugly formatter for DEMONSTRATION ONLY, better stay with the regexp version!
formatter = (value) => {
  let result = '';
  String(value || '').split('').forEach((v, i) => {
    if (i%3 === 0 && i > 0) {
      result += ',' + v; // <-- every 3 digits concatenate a comma
    } else {
      result += v;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```